# How can a substance have a higher boiling point but lower melting point than another substance?

Tags: boiling-point, melting-point

Looking at 1,3-Butadiene and Isoprene, I'm wondering: why does Isoprene have a higher boiling point, but a lower melting point than 1,3-Butadiene?

I'm thinking this might be because the Methyl group on C(2) in Isoprene might cause it's lattice to be less tightly packed, thus requiring less energy to be split (-> lower melting point). As both substances can't form any ion-ion, nor dipole-dipole, nor hydrogen bonds, Isoprene probably has a higher boiling point than 1,3-Butadiene because it has a larger surface, enabling it to develop stronger London (VdW) forces.

Can anyone confirm/ disprove this?

Thanks a lot in advance!